# Regular expression, match anything but these strings

Tags: regex, regex-negation, splunk, regex-lookarounds

Within Splunk I have a number of field extractions for extracting values from uri stems. I have a few which match a specific pattern, I now want another regex which matches anything but these.

```
^/SiteName/[^/]*/(?<a_request_type>((?!Process)|(?!process)|(?!Assets)|(?!assets))[^/]+)
```

The regex above is what I have so far. I am expecting the negative lookaheads to prevent it from matching Process, process, assets or Assets. However it seems that the [^/]+ after these lookaheads can then go ahead and match these strings anyway. Resulting in this regex sometimes overriding the other regexes I wrote to accept these strings

What is the correct syntax for me to make the regex match any string, other than those specified in the negative lookaheads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative lookaheads **do not consume** any of the string being searched. When you want multiple negative lookaheads, there is no need to separate them with `|` (OR). Try this:

```
^/SiteName/[^/]*/(?<a_request_type>((?![Pp]rocess)(?![Aa]ssets))[^/]+)
```

Note that I have combined your lookaheads (`[Pp]rocess` and `[Aa]ssets`) to make the regular expression more concise.

[Live test](https://regex101.com/r/dR1mT0/2).

Comment: I know, I can't mark it for 3 minutes after you post it. 5 seconds to go ;)

Comment: I think you can further reduce it to `(?![Pp]rocess|[Aa]ssets)`. @dahui `\b(?:(?!foo)|(?!bar))\w+` [can still be foo or bar](https://regex101.com/r/xW7zC2/1). But `\b(?!foo|bar)\w+` [cannot be either](https://regex101.com/r/kO9wG6/1). It's a logic mistake.

Comment: Yeah so it was not matching one, and would match the next, I get you. Thanks